# Smoothly Transitioning Between ReactJS Prop Changes

Tags: reactjs

There are two buttons that toggle the layout of an item. When either button is clicked, I'd like the item to fade out, change, then fade back in.

Using ReactJS, I'm running into two problems:

1. Using `componentDidUpdate` to trigger the "fade back in" event causes a loop; changing the state re-triggers `componentDidUpdate` endlessly.
2. Using `componentWillReceiveProps` allows me to update the class on the element to have it fade out, but it also immediately changes the layout. I need to delay the change until it's invisible.

Thoughts? Have I constructed this wrong?

(The code is below, but something is broken in Stack's version that works in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nathanziarek/69z2wepo/15009/)

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
     return { visible: " x-hidden" };
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div className={"hello" + this.state.visible}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
     this.setState({ visible: "" })
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
     // The item is changing, make it invisible
        // Wait until it's done being invisible before changing
        // anything?
     this.setState({ visible: " x-hidden" })
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
     // The item has changed, make it visible
        // Setting anything here causes this function
        // to get called again, creating a loop
     // this.setState({ visible: "" })
    }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.label}</button>;
    },
    handleClick: function() {
     React.render(
         <span>
             <Button label="Universe"/>
                <Button label="World"/>
                <Hello name={this.props.label} />
            </span>, 
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
    }
});
 
React.render(
    <span>
        <Button label="Universe"/>
        <Button label="World"/>
        <Hello name="_______" />
    </span>, 
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.hello {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 300ms opacity linear;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms opacity linear;
}

.x-hidden { opacity: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>

<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using React's [`CSSTransitionGroup`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) add-on component. You'll have to do some restructuring, but this will give you the behavior you want without having to add a bunch of logic around setting CSS classes; React will take care of animating (in your case, fading) components that are entering/leaving the DOM.

*Unrelated*: I would also avoid re-rendering your entire component like how you're doing it in your button click event. This breaks the flow of React and will inevitably cause problems. Prefer changing state and pushing down new props.

Comment: You know, I was using that, but didn't see why it was better than just changing my classes. This might be the perfect reason. (To your unrelated: I've searched high and low for a better way to do this--the end result was that this is OK because 'react's DOM diffing tool is so fast'. I'll keep hunting!)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to have both on screen then to do the fade ***entirely*** with css, and essentially completely omit React from the process other than to place the appropriate classes.

If you're fading between them you need both sets of contents anyway.  That, in turn, means there's no reason to not have these in the document, and that in turn means it's just CSS hide/show tomfoolery, and there's no need for any kind of React lifecycle stuff.

You're overcomplicating it by trying to have React handle way too much.

Supporting CSS:

```
#foo span { 
  opacity: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}

#foo span.show { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

Then the relevant React:

```
var Foo = react.createComponent({ 

  render: function() { 

    var showKey = this.props.showKey,
        Things = {
          a: 'Apple',
          b: 'Bear',
          c: 'Cold inevitable doom'
        };

    return (
      <div id="foo">
        { Things.map(X,k) { 
          return <span class={(showKey === k)? 'show':undefined}>{X}</span> 
        }}
      </div>
    );

  }

});
```

You'll find that as you switch that control's showKey, it will fade in and out its relevant contents as appropriate.

Comment: This is interesting -- It's how I would have handled it pre-React. I think the issue is going to be that what I'm *actually* styling are search results that can be displayed as rows, grids, or tables. I don't think I want to have each of those three in the DOM * 100 search results. But ... maybe I need to think about how this built more. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: the alternative is to constantly thrash your dom adding them and removing them.

a couple hundred elements are nothing to a browser.